# How to compose and send an SNMP response in C

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

There are many demo net-snmp programs which receive SNMP response from agent and parse it. But, I want the opposite functionality, suppose I want to send an SNMP Response PDU using UDP/IP. I already have the values I want to send to the manager (e.g., sysName.0 = "ABCDEFGH").

Can someone point me to some API's which will accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want is calling an `SNMP agent`. 
If we take an SNMP v2c, the SNMP response PDU is nearly same as request's one, but it has other request type field and non-null values for variable binding.
For plain C I don't know an easy way to write simple SNMP agent as standalone program - only make your own parser and serializer and work with network on your own. Using `net-snmp` you can write agent module or submodule to use with net-snmp daemon (http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/). Also could take perl and write custom handler for traps (as trap receiver) and other requests (as agent) as `net-snmp` has embedded perl interpreter
Or, if you can use `c++` you could take `agent++` library ( https://agentpp.com/ ) and write standalone SNMP agent program.